# Cannot find a LSB script for mopidy

Tags: raspbmc, apt, mopidy

I'm trying to install **mopidy** on my Pi running **raspbmc** but it complains about missing LSB script:

```
$ sudo apt-get install mopidy
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
The following extra packages will be installed:
  gstreamer0.10-plugins-good libtag1-vanilla libtag1c2a
Suggested packages:
  mopidy-doc
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  gstreamer0.10-plugins-good libtag1-vanilla libtag1c2a mopidy
0 upgraded, 4 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 162 kB/2259 kB of archives.
After this operation, 7107 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue [Y/n]?
Get:1 http://archive.raspbian.org/raspbian/ testing/main mopidy all 0.19.4-2 [162 kB]
Fetched 162 kB in 0s (291 kB/s)
Preconfiguring packages ...
Selecting previously unselected package libtag1-vanilla:armhf.
(Reading database ... 47766 files and directories currently installed.)
Unpacking libtag1-vanilla:armhf (from .../libtag1-vanilla_1.7.2-1_armhf.deb) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libtag1c2a:armhf.
Unpacking libtag1c2a:armhf (from .../libtag1c2a_1.7.2-1_armhf.deb) ...
Selecting previously unselected package gstreamer0.10-plugins-good:armhf.
Unpacking gstreamer0.10-plugins-good:armhf (from .../gstreamer0.10-plugins-good_0.10.31-3
+nmu1_armhf.deb) ...
Selecting previously unselected package mopidy.
Unpacking mopidy (from .../mopidy_0.19.4-2_all.deb) ...
Setting up libtag1-vanilla:armhf (1.7.2-1) ...
Setting up libtag1c2a:armhf (1.7.2-1) ...
Setting up gstreamer0.10-plugins-good:armhf (0.10.31-3+nmu1) ...
Setting up mopidy (0.19.4-2) ...
insserv: dryrun, not creating .depend.boot, .depend.start, and .depend.stop
update-rc.d: error: cannot find a LSB script for mopidy
dpkg: error processing mopidy (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 mopidy
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Would be grateful for help.

Comment: I assume other packages do not show this error during installation with apt-get?

Comment: @Ghanima They don't. I tried installing nginx and adding it via `update-rc.d` and it worked fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally managed to solve the problem by extracting deb package and manually copying mopidy boot script to `/etc/init.d/mopidy`. I also had to manually adjust init script links using `update-rc.d` and `insserv`, because the symlinks weren't removed when uninstalling mopidy via `apt-get remove`.